# Background and Fontface not showing on aspx page

Tags: asp.net, css, html

I have a master template in aspx from which I create other aspx pages from and in the master template I have referenced a css style sheet. For some reason the background image that i've set on the body and the fontface that i've applied is not working anymore. It simply does not show up on any of the aspx pages created from the master template.

I can not for the life of me figure out why it's not showing. In fact, in Visual Studio the background DOES show.

Here is an image of my project directory so you can see how they are all positioned.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bp2uw.png

So I have my stylesheet referenced for all the aspx pages in the base Cafe directory AND the Aspx files in the Secure folder by the simple

```
 <link href="Styles/Coffee.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
<link href="../Styles/Coffee.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
```

So the style sheet has been referenced correctly as some objects do change as they are suppose to.

Here is the code in the css file : http://slexy.org/view/s2OAgP08oS

Also this is thie output of the page in both Visual Studio and the output in the browser :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdyIH.jpg

This was working before just fine, the labels and all text on my aspx page was displaying with the fontface etc. Background was fine in both IE and FF. Don't get what's happened now.

Comment: `Styles/Coffee.css` and this `../Styles/Coffee.css` are different things

Comment: With my limited knowledge of aspx/html/css i've refrenced them like this because the aspx pages i'm using this in are in different locations. These 2 references seem to cover them both.

Answer (score 0):

Okay folks, rookie mistake on my part. It was the fact that I wasn't referencing to the fontface files or the image correctly. Because I had /Fontface and /Images it was going into CSS STYLES FODLER/Images.. When in fact it was in the Images folder of the directory above.

So doing this fixes it.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'MolotRegular';
src: url('../Fontface/Molot-webfont.eot');
src: url('../Fontface/Molot-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../Fontface/Molot-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../Fontface/Molot-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('../Fontface/Molot-webfont.svg#MolotRegular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}

body
{
font-family: 'MolotRegular', Arial, Helvettica;
background-image: url("../Images/background.jpg");
margin-top: 0px;

}
```

TL:DR : Do not trust the output in Visual Studio. It's a LIE!